# Graphviz node ordering

Tags: graphviz

I want to have a diagram which has the layout as follwing :

[image]

But when i wrote the codes like this:

```
digraph g {
a->b->c;
{rank=same;b,d,e,f,g,h}
d->g [weight = 1];
d->f [weight = 10];
}
```

And comes like this:

[image]

The dot guide even recommends this:

```
    Edge weights also play a role when nodes are constrained to the same rank. 
    Edges with non-zero weight between these nodes are aimed across the rank 
in the samedirection (left-to-right, or top-to-bottom in a rotated drawing) as far
 as possible. This fact may be exploited to adjust node ordering by placing
 invisible edges (style="invis") where needed.
```

I wander why it not work?

Answer (score 2):

add the following line in your graph:

```
f->g[style=invis];
```

Comment: If add this line,the output come like expected.But 'weight' is not need.I wander why 'weight' not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
digraph g {
    a->b->c;
    {rank=same;b,d,e,f,g,h}
    d->g [weight = 0];
    d->f [weight = 1];
}
```

Works as you wish.

But, I also don't know why

```
d->g [weight = 1];
d->f [weight = 2];
```

doesn't work.

---

Maybe it depends on layout type, `neato` or `dot` or etc. See https://graphviz.gitlab.io/docs/attrs/weight/

---

Also

```
digraph {
    a -> b -> c;
    d->g
    d->f 
    {rank = same; b;d;e;f;g;h;}
}
```

Works. [Source](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c%3B%0A%20%20%20%20d-%3Eg%0A%20%20%20%20d-%3Ef%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7Brank%20%3D%20same%3B%20b%3Bd%3Be%3Bf%3Bg%3Bh%3B%7D%0A%7D)